# Not able to login into Ubuntu account due to moved home directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I was renaming home directory user of my another Ubuntu account using terminal:

```
sudo usermod -d /home/<new_home_directory_name> <another_username>
```

By mistake, I missed `-m` option between `<directory name>` and `<user_name>`. Now I'm not able to login into that account.

When I login to that user using `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, `pwd` returns `/`. 
I can see 'Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop' when I do `ls` in `<older_home_directory>`.

Let me know how can I recover my account as it is the main account.

Comment: What output do you see for `ls /home/*` ?

Answer (score 1):

When you forgot the `-m` option to `usermod`, you didn't *move* the home directory at all.  You already observed that the old directory is still there and visible from `ls`, so you can undo your previous change by calling `usermod` again:

```
sudo usermod -d /home/<old_home_directory_name> <username>
```

Answer (score 0):

On a terminal you will have / as your home, as you pointed out. So go back there and just change your home in your passwd file...

```
Ctrl+Alt+F1

sudo vi /etc/passwd
```

Find your username, the 6th field is your home directory. Set it to your home... e.g. mine is /home/number9. Save and exit that file. Login and be happy.

Note, if you don't know vi/vim, use nano or your favorite editor.

Note further, if your home is encrypted, you will need to follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17332/how-can-i-move-an-encrypted-home-directory-to-another-partition). If you are moving it to a new location and not partition, just use the location, not the partition.

Comment: Hi, I did the same and it is working as earlier. But I want to change the name of my 'home' directory. When I try to do that, it changed the name but I'm seeing cross sign on that home directory when seen from another account. And then again I am unable to login to that account. When I logged in using Ctrl+Alt+F1, I can see "Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop" and README.txt file under that home directory. Can't I change the name of my home directory.

Comment: @GeniusGo you should be able to change the name of your home directory... you would login as your user, sudo vi /etc/passwd, and change the name. Know that you must also change the name of the actual dir. e.g. if your old dir was /home/fred and you want /home/flintstone, you would change it in /etc/passwd and then cd /home ; mv fred flintstone

Comment: Then it gives me error: 
mv: cannot move '<old_directory_name>' to '<new_directory_name>': Device or resource busy

Comment: @GeniusGo then you are probably in the directory, or something has it open. something like lsof |grep old_directory_name should give you some insight

Comment: My old home directory seems to be encrypted with ecryptfs. May be that is one reason it is not allowing me to rename the directory.

Comment: Ah, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17332/how-can-i-move-an-encrypted-home-directory-to-another-partition) should help.

Answer (score 0):

If I got everything right, you only changed the home-dir in the /etc/passwd.
You can rename the home dir: `sudo mv /home/<old_home_directory_name> /home/<new_home_directory_name>`

Answer (score -2):

Start Ubuntu as root and restore:
Press the Shift key during boot to get the grub menu and select a revocery mode.